# Is it right to say, "Ever since I set eyes on you, I was wondering where I had seen you before?"

Tags: sentence-construction

1. Is the

   > where I had seen you before

   before part constructed correctly? If not, how should it be constructed?
2. If this incident is being related to another person, we would say,

   > Ever since I saw him that day, I was wondering where I had seen him before

   wouldn't we?

Comment: Escher meets the perfect :)

Comment: It would better with the present perfect: “Ever since I set eyes on you, I have been wondering where I had seen you before?” “Where” is an interrogative clause subordinator introducing the subordinate interrogative clause “where I had seen you before?”. The meaning is “Ever since I set eyes on you, I have been wondering about the answer to the question ‘Where had I seen you before”’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in question 1 is correct: **seen** occurred before **that day**, so present perfect simple **had seen** is the right tense.

The text in question 2 needs a small change: the same change should be made to the original sentence.

> Ever since I saw him that day, I **have been wondering** where I had seen him before

When you use the expression **ever since**, you are talking about something that has been happening for a while, and is still happening. You therefore need to use the present perfect contiunuous **have been wondering** rather than past continuous **was wondering** which we normally use about things that have finished.

Note, though, that we use **was wondering** as a backshift when asking a polite question, for example:

> I wonder whether you would like to have a drink with me after work - *present*
>   I was wondering whether you would like to have a drink with me after work. - *backshifted*

Comment: I think it would have been helpful to also bring out the point about "where I had seen you before" being a subordinate interrogative clause.